# Can we increase the height of Toast notification in WP7

Tags: fonts, height, windows-phone-7.1, toast

When we receive Toast Notification during the App  in Background/ or not running, the Toast is displayed by Wp7 OS. Can this display of OS be modified, I mean is there any way we can increase its height or font size. The message I receive is too long to fit whole message in the Toast message.

Thanks and Regards,
Kanaya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to customize the standard toast UI beyond the text you pass to it.

If your text it to long either shorten it or use text which encourages the user to tap it (and thereby launch your app) so you can then display the full message.

Comment: Thanks Matt, for you valuable Answer.